Does paying taxes and insurance for a separate property using post-marriage income render the separate property a community property?
For community property states (e.g. California), if I have two properties, one is separate and one is community. Does paying taxes, insurance, or ADU/remodeling costs for my separate property using post-marriage income render the separate property a community property? Why or why not? Thanks.

Does this answer your question? Home community and separate property

@ohwilleke No, it does not because it does not discuss whether using the income during marriage to pay for taxes, insurance, and ADU/remodeling will render a separate property having community property nature.

Actually, if you read carefully, that exact point is discussed.

In re Marriage of Branco is a relevant case where using community property for acquisition costs lead to community acquiring interest in the property.
Adding an ADU or remodeling is considered an improvement, i.e.: moneys spent on this are acquisition costs. So using community property to finance those may lead to community acquiring interest in the produced improvement.
In re Marriage of Wolfe is another relevant case, where while no claim of community interest was made, the community was reimbursed for moneys spent on the separate property. That can apply for all the expenses, including taxes, insurance, and improvements.

Do you know if opening a separate account using solely my name and if I only fund the ADU or remodeling cost using the fund from that separate account after marriage will not lead to community acquiring interest in the property?

@HelloDarkWorld account title is not an evidence for the property to be community or separate

So does that mean regardless of title of my account, any income not from gift, bequest, or inheritance...etc will be treated as community property after marriage? Also, what do you mean by "the community was reimbursed for moneys spent on the separate property. That can apply for all the expenses, including taxes, insurance, and improvements"?

@HelloDarkWorld you should probably talk to your attorney at the details of your personal situation
